# Precompiled headers using boost libs takes very long to compile

Tags: c++

I'm creating a software that relies on a lot of boost libs and, as compilation became slower and slower (minutes), I've packed all the libs used over and over in a precompiled header (say 20-ish boost libs and 20 std libs), hoping that it would solve the issue.

Today, I realized that a vanilla hello-world.cpp (that does not even includes the damn precompiled header) takes 15s to build when i compile with the precompiled header. The precompiled header is 300MB or so.

Hence, the questions are:

-is that kind of slowdown expected, for a precompiled header this size? 
(I secretely hope that I made some kind of monstruous mistake and I'd be very happy if one of you could tell me that he routinely works with a 2GB precompiled header and things are smooth)

-if this kind of slowdown is expected, then I'm not convinced at all at the usefullness of a precompiled header. Am I missing something?

compiler:

```
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
```

commandline:

```
g++ -include common-header.hpp -Winvalid-pch -c vanilla-hello-world.cpp
```

Comment: By precompiled do you mean proprocessed?  A header is not stand-alone translation unit and can't be "precompiled" to my knowledge.

Comment: thats vanilla-hello-world.cpp, and Gurg if it takes 15s for building a prog which doesn't includes headers, there's a problem then.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) for your knowledge then

Comment: but then again I compile my vanilla code together with the preprocessed header and it is -included as per the command-line above

Comment: The commands here do not demonstrate use of a precompiled header. Are you sure there's anything precompiled here at all? Otherwise, if common-header.hpp just includes the entirety of Boost, then *of course* it will take a long time compile since gcc has to read through all those headers every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> packed all the libs used over and over in a precompiled header

This is your problem, just include what you need.

Each TU still has to consult this massive precomped header.

Comment: not sure I follow you: the libs that are used over and over are certainly the ones that are needed, which makes them good candidates for inclusion (?!)

Comment: Ok, so this was sort of the answer:
the PCH got really too big which was slowing me.
Looking hard at how to break the project into different compilation units (with their own PCHs) solved the compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla_hello_world.cpp file should begin with #include of the precompiled header (before any other C++ statements other than comments.

Your question should include the command line used and the console messages produced by:

1. The command to compile the PCH
2. The command to compile vanilla_hello_world.cpp without the PCH
3. The command to compile vanilla_hello_world.cpp using the PCH.

Use "time gcc ..." to display the times for each of the above.

If PCH is working, time #3 will be less than time #2.

It is quite likely that time #1 + time #2 will be greater than #3.  The point of PCH is #1 is rarely needed (often only once).